# Is Tie::File lazily loading a file?

Tags: perl, arrays, tie

I'm planning on writing a simple text viewer, which I'd expect to be able to deal with very large sized files. I was thinking of using `Tie::File` for this, and kind of paginate the lines. Is this loading the lines lazily, or all of them at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't load the whole file. From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File):

> The file is not loaded into memory, so this will work even for gigantic files.

Comment: but to find line 1830234, it has to read the entire file up to that point (though not all into memory)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see from [its source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MJD/Tie-File-0.96/lib/Tie/File.pm) it stores only used lines in memory. And yes, it loads data only when needed.

You can limit amount of used memory with `memory` parameter.

It also tracks offsets of all lines in the file to optimize disk access.